# Why is an app module from a different project showing up in my current project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter, android-studio-3.5

[image: Screenshot]

Please check the above screenshot for a better understanding of my problem.

The app module of another app that I was working on showed
   up in my current app and I'm not sure how to get rid of it. 

Both apps were created using flutter and I had opened the Android folder to
   build the apk but whenever I'm doing this the first error I'm getting
   is, 

`Project 'firebase_auth' not found in root project 'android'.`

`firebase_auth` is used in the previous application and not current one
   and it is forcing me to add all the same dependencies.

 Even after I've done that it doesn't even recognize my current app module and only runs the previous app

**UPDATE-1:** I changed the directory of my previous app and now it seems to be searching for it, I'm getting this error:

`The specified project directory 'C:\Users\thear\FlutterProjects\xxxxx\android' does not exist.`

 That is the old directory of my previous app

**UPDATE-2:** Changing the directory and detaching the Gradle project of the previous app helps but I still don't understand why my project is looking for the previous project, what is connecting the two.

Comment: Hi, this may happen when your new project path(location) is as the same as the old project. is it so? then create your project somewhere else and try again.

Comment: did you copy folders ? or pubspec.yaml file

Comment: try to clear invalidate caches of android studio and restart the IDE maybe it's work.

Comment: @Soli They were in different folders but i still changed the directory of the previous app but when i open my current project it seems to be searching for my previous app, it says "Cannot load settings from file 'C:\Users\thear\FlutterProjects\xxxxx\android\app\android-app.iml' and that's the old directory of my previous app, I just want to know why it's looking for it and not recognizing it's own app module

Comment: All projects need some settings to go. I've faced like the problem you have when trying to copy a project codes and deploy it in my own. The solution was to create a new (Flutter)project and redo it again. This will create and put the settings needed for the project. Sometimes a minor miss in settings will cause whole project not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution for this is to:

1. Close the project
2. Go to the `$project_folder\android\.idea` folder
3. Delete `modules.xml` and `workspace.xml` files
4. Open the android folder again in Android Studio, the modules loads correctly.

I am not sure why this happens but deleting those configuration files solved my problems with the wrong modules loading.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will look into it soon and mark your answer correct if it solves my problem.

Comment: @ArhaamPatvi How did it go?

Comment: Worked for me on a similar issue I had with the modules, thank you!